# Craft Commerce: Variable "product" does not exist

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

My shop has one product. As such there isn't much point in me having a page displaying all products.

When I paste in my template code for my single product into Cart Commerce's main index template I get the error ***Variable "product" does not exist*** on the following code:

```
{% for purchasable in product.variants %}

    <option {% if purchasable.stock <= 0 and purchasable.unlimitedStock == false %}disabled {% endif %} value="{{ purchasable.purchasableId }}">{{ purchasable.description }} {{ purchasable.price|currency(cart.currency) }}</option>

{% endfor %}
```

Why is this being thrown up and how do I remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`product` will only be available by default if you're viewing the template set in the CP under that Product Type’s settings, and it's set up with a URL format:

[image: Craft Commerce Product Type edit screen]

If you want to display your product elsewhere on your site you will need to set it to a variable, using a [Product Query](https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/products-variants.html#querying-products):

```
{% set myProduct = craft.products.one() %}
```

…you can then loop through this Product's Variants (or just use `myProduct.getDefaultVariant()` if it only has one):

```
{# This example is part of an "add-to-cart" form! #}

Configure your {{ myProduct.title }}:

<select name="purchasableIds[]">
    {% for purchasable in myProduct.getVariants() %}
        <option
            {% if not purchasable.getIsAvailable() %}disabled{% endif %}
            value="{{ purchasable.purchasableId }}">
            {{ purchasable.description }}
            {{ purchasable.price | currency(cart.paymentCurrency) }}
        </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

See the Commerce Documentation for more information about [adding products to the cart](https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/orders-carts.html#adding-items-to-a-cart)!